# How to custom domainAxis LineChart flutter_charts

Tags: charts, flutter, point

I implemented a line chart using [flutter_charts](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_charts) library but I don't know how to change the domainAxis in chart. I already put the data in array.

```
final data = [
  new LinearSales(9, 1),
  new LinearSales(10, 0),
  new LinearSales(11, 0),
  new LinearSales(12, 0),...
];
```

But the display look like this

[image]

Please help...

Comment: please provide your complete code implementation